Sending traces from Sentry to Otel collector, instead of the other way around?
I have a classic Flask/jinja2 web app that does some processing on the backend from an API call. There is something weird going on, and I'd like to be able to trace the request from the frontend to the backend, and I'm using the quick and dirty Sentry script to get tracing in the front end:
 <script
  src="https://js.sentry-cdn.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxc6169bb7a.min.js"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>

This works well, and I can see what I want to see in the sentry tracing dashboard. Now, on the flask side, I use the opentemeletry-python-distro and a bunch of contrib instrumentors, which I send directly to Grafana cloud Tempo via an OTel gateway. Now, I'm wondering if it's possible to send the sentry traces to that gateway, as well as add the traceID header to calls to my flask backend. The sentry docs seems to say that it's possible to send OTel spans to Sentry, but I can't find anywhere if it's possible to send sentry spans to an OTel collector.
Has anyone managed to get full front to back trace coverage in Tempo before?

I don't know Sentry, it might do way more than I imagine so keep that in mind: Faro can initiate traces an forward that to OTEL-compatible collectors and backends.
